# Error 1962: No operating system found. Boot sequence will automatically repeat

Tags: boot, freebsd

I installed the FreeBSD 10.0 from a pen-drive to be the only system in the computer and the installation looked perfect.

When I turned the computer on to use the system from the hard-drive it shows:

> Error 1962: No operating system found. Boot sequence will automatically repeat.

I checked the disk `ada0` with `gpart show` and the partitions are there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gpart` to make the harddisk bootable. See the manual page, especially the section BOOTSTRAPPING.